# Use input fields like variables

Tags: graphql

Here's the way I pass variables now:

```
mutation Test($a: Int, $b: Int, $c: Int, $d: Int) {
  test(a: $a, b: $b, c: $c, d: $d) {
    id
  }
}

// Example
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}
```

I want to put these variables into an input:

```
// Example
{
  first: {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  },
  second: {
    c: 3,
    d: 4
  }
}

// GraphQL
input TestInput {
  first: First
  second: Second
}

input First {
  a: Int
  b: Int
}

input Second {
  c: Int
  d: Int
}

// The code below doesn't work
mutation Test($input: TestInput) {
  test(a: $input.first.a, b: $input.first.b, c: $input.second.c, d: $input.second.d) {
    id
  }
}
```

This approach will save me from creating mapping functions and VM/Models in my code.
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GraphQL does not currently support accessing individual fields on variable values that are objects. To make this work, you need to change your `test` field to accept a single argument of the type `TestInput`:

```
type Mutation {
  test(input: TestInput): SomeType
}
```

then you can do:

```
mutation Test($input: TestInput) {
  test(input: $input) {
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I cannot modify the schema :( Anyway, now I know that this feature is not supported. Thanks!